# LocalDB is not supported on this platform error

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently studying .net core3.1 and following microsoft provided tutorial. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-mac

when I type "dotnet ef database update" I get an error message that says "LocalDB is not supported on this platform" .

what is the problem ? and how can I fix this?

I am using a macbook.

thank you

Comment: Whats your Operating System?

Comment: oh sorry i didn't add that. Its Mac OS

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Localdb is Windows only. You have to use SqLite instead

Comment: So... how can I do that? Would you mind teach me ?

Comment: I'm a little busy right now to write a propper answer, but for starter you should install [SqLite provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: I think I got it?! Thank you guys so much for helping me